# What happens if I upload a new version of my application on App Store, that is only ARMv7?

Tags: ios, itunes, ipod, armv7, armv6

I have a "Ready for sale" application on iTunes connect that is a universal app for iPhone and iPad.

My application is suitable also for ARMv6 devices such as ipod touch 1g/2g and old iPhone.

If i upload a new version of my application that is compiled only for ARMv7 architecture, what happens to an ipod user? Continue to use the old version?

Thanks for support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what would happen if you just upload it, but if you add arvm7 as a required device capability in Info.plist old device users would be able to continue using the previous version and would be unable to update, and new users would have to have an armv7 device.

Answer (score 0):

xCode won't let you load the update. It will give you the following error:
This bundle is invalid. UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities in the Info.plist may not contain values that would prevent this application from running on devices that were supported by previous versions.